# Relacionar 4 claves foráneas de una tabla con una clave primaria de otra tabla

Tags: mysql

tengo 2 tablas, una de ellas normalizada donde registro el seguimiento del despacho de un producto, dentro de otros campos los que me interesan para esta consulta son 4:
Recepción de pedido
Salida del producto
Llegada del producto
Entrega del producto
Estas 4 columnas son de tipo date-time, por cada columna de éste seguimiento quiero colocar una columna que registre el id del operador que actualiza la traza del producto, cada una de ellas está normalizada y son claves foráneas.
La otra tabla contiene la información del operador (id, nombre, apellido, etc.).
Mi pregunta es: puedo relacionar cada clave foránea de la primera con el id de la segunda tabla?

Comment: Respuesta: Sí. Ahora, ¿cuál es el problema? Si tienes alguno, muestra el diseño de las tablas, la consulta que estás intentando y los resultados que obtienes.

Answer (score 0):

Aquí está el código y las tablas, el resultado es que coloca el mismo operador en las 4 columnas.

```
SELECT eventos_despacho.id_despacho, eventos_despacho.numero_evento, eventos_despacho.fecha_hora_despacho, eventos_despacho.id_operador_despacho, usuarios.apellidos_usuario AS operadorDespacho, eventos_despacho.id_operador_salida, usuarios.apellidos_usuario AS operadorSalida, eventos_despacho.id_operador_llegada, usuarios.apellidos_usuario AS operadorLlegada, eventos_despacho.id_operador_respuesta, usuarios.apellidos_usuario AS operadorRespuesta FROM usuarios INNER JOIN eventos_despacho ON usuarios.id_usuarios = eventos_despacho.id_operador_despacho
```

WHERE eventos_despacho.numero_evento = '1807031212-01100'

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]